# Why would Mobify not work when self-hosted?

Tags: javascript, responsive, mobify, mobify-js

I have a website that uses Mobify to show a responsive layout. Mobify is shutting down its services. So, I am trying to move files from Mobify to my own site so that my responsive layout will continue to work. This includes the mobify.js file, the a.js file, the style.css, and fonts.css .

I'm able to get my mobile content to appear. However, my mobile CSS stops working. The files I'm hosting are the same files from the Mobify site. All I'm doing is changing the reference from Mobify's site to where I have them hosted. Is there a reason this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error I was having was for Mobify Studio. My solution was to place all files in the same folder: the mobify.js file, the a.js file, the style.css, and fonts.css. I had placed the css files in a "stylesheets" folder originally (separate from the js files), and something in the JS didn't like that. Putting all stylesheets in the same folder as the js files solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Mobify.me doesn't generate a Mobify.js file. It sounds like you are using Mobify Studio. Mobify doesn't have plans to shut down Mobify Studio yet.

Let me know if there's anything else I can help with!

Kind regards,

Eric